# Unexpected token in db2 sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, db2, entity

This is my query:

```
    "SELECT t FROM LeerkrachtEntity t WHERE t = (SELECT l.leerkracht FROM LesEntity l WHERE l.id = :lesId)  AND t IN (SELECT k.teachers FROM KlasEntity k WHERE k.id = :klasId) AND t.id = :leerkrachtId"
```

This is what hibernate does:

```
    Hibernate: 
/* SELECT
    t 
FROM
    LeerkrachtEntity t 
WHERE
    t = (
        SELECT
            l.leerkracht 
        FROM
            LesEntity l 
        WHERE
            l.id = :lesId
    )  
    AND t IN (
        SELECT
            k.teachers 
        FROM
            KlasEntity k 
        WHERE
            k.id = :klasId
    ) 
    AND t.id = :leerkrachtId */ select
        leerkracht0_.person_id as person_i1_12_,
        leerkracht0_1_.email as email2_12_,
        leerkracht0_1_.familienaam as familien3_12_,
        leerkracht0_1_.voornaam as voornaam4_12_ 
    from
        leerkracht leerkracht0_ 
    inner join
        person leerkracht0_1_ 
            on leerkracht0_.person_id=leerkracht0_1_.person_id 
    where
        leerkracht0_.person_id=(
            select
                lesentity1_.person_id 
            from
                les lesentity1_,
                leerkracht leerkracht2_ 
            inner join
                person leerkracht2_1_ 
                    on leerkracht2_.person_id=leerkracht2_1_.person_id 
            where
                lesentity1_.person_id=leerkracht2_.person_id 
                and lesentity1_.les_id=?
        ) 
        and (
            leerkracht0_.person_id in (
                select
                    . 
                from
                    klas klasentity3_,
                    leerkracht_klas teachers4_,
                    leerkracht leerkracht5_ 
                inner join
                    person leerkracht5_1_ 
                        on leerkracht5_.person_id=leerkracht5_1_.person_id 
                where
                    klasentity3_.klas_id=teachers4_.klas_id 
                    and teachers4_.person_id=leerkracht5_.person_id 
                    and klasentity3_.klas_id=?
            )
        ) 
        and leerkracht0_.person_id=?
```

I get following error:

```
    16:48:27.475 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - unexpected token: KLAS required: )
```

I am trying to get a leerkrachtEntity where in the database 'lesId' and 'klasId' are connected.
Please help me. I don't know what is wrong.

---

When I use this part of the query, everything works.

```
       "SELECT t FROM LeerkrachtEntity t WHERE t = (SELECT l.leerkracht FROM LesEntity l WHERE l.id = :lesId)  AND t.id = :leerkrachtId"
```

It goes wrong here:

```
    t IN (SELECT k.teachers FROM KlasEntity k WHERE k.id = :klasId) AND
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an object called `KLAS` or should that be `KlasEntity`?

Comment: It should be KlasEntity, but in my query I use KlasEntity?

Comment: In the hibernate query within the where clause for `leerkracht0_.person_id` you have `from klas klasentity3_`. Naively, I would say that this should reference `KlasEntity instead of `klas`.

Comment: How can I change this? The hibernate query is generated by the other query.

Comment: find out why it generates `KLAS`. Hibernate does not come up with that name by itself. Someone in your code, you need to connect your `Klas` object with the `KlasEntity` table. For the beginning, search for Klas (whole words only) in all your files of your project. That should give you a clue.

Comment: KLAS is the tablename.

#Entity
#Table(name = "KLAS")
public class KlasEntity implements Serializable {

Comment: according to your query, `KlasEntity` is the table name so try `#Table(name = "KlasEntity")`. If you are sure that KLAS is the real table name, then I am surprised that your query works.

Comment: The table name is KLAS.

create table KLAS
(
   KLAS_ID              BIGINT                 not null
      generated by default as identity,
   SCHOOLJAAR_ID        BIGINT                 not null,
   SCHOOL_ID            BIGINT,
   NAAM                 VARCHAR(20)            not null,
   constraint P_PK_KLAS primary key (KLAS_ID)
);

Comment: How come that `SELECT t FROM LeerkrachtEntity t WHERE t = (SELECT l.leerkracht FROM LesEntity l WHERE l.id = :lesId)  AND t IN (SELECT k.teachers FROM KlasEntity k WHERE k.id = :klasId) AND t.id = :leerkrachtId` works? It references `KlasEntity `.

Comment: It is not a native query, it is an entity query. It searches the entity, which is mapped with the tables.